# is showing equality 'sufficient' for proof?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this question: [Prove that function is linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943224/prove-that-function-is-linear)

My math is pretty bad, so I tried to work through it as an exercise, the problem is quoted below:

> Let f be a differentiable function such that for every x and h it holds that f(x+h)−f(x)=hf′(x). Prove that f(x)=kx+n where k and n are constants.

Is substituting the f(x) we are trying to prove into the differential equation and showing the equality holds not sufficient to prove that f(x)=kx+n? The differential equation reduces to hk = hk when this substitution is made. I'm wondering because neither answer used this line of reasoning, and I have too little confidence in my math to be sure it is right.

This would probably work better as a comment in that question, but I don't have 50 rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite - your question is asking you to show that the differential equation implies the function to be a straight line; it seems you've tried to prove the reverse implication.

For the actual proof, the following approach works:

Taking $x=0$:

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=hf'(x)\implies f(h)-f(0)=hf'(0)\implies f(h)=f(0)+hf'(0)\space \forall h$$

So, $f(x)=kx+n$, with $n=f(0)$, $k=f'(0)$.

Comment: Thanks. So I did "B implies A" when I needed to show that "A implies B". In some cases (not this one I guess) won't these be equivalent? How do I know when I can "work backwards" from the statement I am trying to prove?

Comment: It really varies quite a bit depending on question, though I will say that whilst looking at "B implies A" won't necessarily give you your solution, it can be useful for gaining intuition for how to prove the other direction.